# R Shiny Tool works with simulated data, not real data (Error in t.default(inputdata) : argument is not a matrix)

Tags: r, shiny

I am having an issue with my r shiny tool.  I worked too hard to replicate the issue, and got the tool to work with the simulated data but i receive the error:

```
Error in t.default(inputdata) : argument is not a matrix
```

coming from server.R whenever i try to run the same code with my real data set.

The tool I am creating is a simple typing tool used for segmentation, I want to have a single output of predicted class upon selecting a few characteristics.  Here is the code for the tool as it works for the simulated data:

```
# Simulation of the Analysis
library(MASS)
library(poLCA)

#Simulate data set
V1 <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.45, 0.05, 0.2) )
V2 <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.25, 0.15) )
V3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:5], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01) )
V4 <- sample( LETTERS[1:3], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.65) )
V5 <- sample( LETTERS[1:3], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.65, 0.2, 0.15) )
V6 <- sample( LETTERS[1:3], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5, 0.45, 0.05) )
V7 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7) )
V8 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.55, 0.45) )
V9 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.8, 0.2) )
V10 <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 521, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.6, 0.4) )
test.data <- cbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10)
test.data <- as.data.frame(test.data)

#Simulate LCA 
test.lca.formula <- cbind(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8, V9, V10) ~ 1
test.lca <- poLCA(test.lca.formula, test.data, nclass = 5, maxiter = 10000)
testlca.predclass <- test.lca$predclass
test.data <- cbind(test.data, testlca.predclass)

#Simulate LDA
attach(test.data)
test.lda <- lda(testlca.predclass ~ V1 + V4 + V7, test.data)
testlda.predict <- predict(test.lda)
testldapredict.class <- (testlda.predict$class)
testclasstab.realvpred <- table(testldapredict.class, testlca.predclass)
testclasstab.realvpred

#Simulate Trained LDA
testldamodel.traindata <- sort(sample(1:521, 100))
test.lda2 <- lda(testlca.predclass ~ V1 + V4 + V7, test.data, subset=testldamodel.traindata)
testlda2.predict <- predict(test.lda2)
testlda2predict.class <- (testlda2.predict$class)
testclasstab.realvpred2 <- table(testlda2predict.class, (testlca.predclass[testldamodel.traindata]))
testclasstab.realvpred2

#server.R
library(shiny)
test.lda2 <- lda(testlca.predclass ~ V1 + V4 + V7, test.data, subset=testldamodel.traindata)
class <- function(v1, v4, v7){
inputdata <- c(v1, v4, v7)
pred_data <- as.data.frame(t(inputdata))
colnames(pred_data) <- c("V1", "V4", "V7")
testlda2.predictions <- predict(test.lda2, pred_data)
testlda2predictions.class <- testlda2.predictions$class
return(testlda2predictions.class)
}
shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
output$class <- renderText({class(input$v1, input$v4, input$v7)
})    
})

#ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("User Class Prediction Tool"),  
sidebarPanel(
selectInput("v1", label = h4("Mustach:"),
            list ("Soul Patch" = "A", "Regular" = "B", "Handle Bar" = "C", "Walrus" = "D", "ZZ Top" = "E")),    
selectInput("v4", label = h4("Hair:"),
            list("None" = "A", "Some" = "B", "Lots" = "C")),
selectInput("v7", label = h4("Sun Glasses:"),
            list ("Yes" = "A", "No" = "B"))
),  
mainPanel(
tabPanel("Class", h2(textOutput('class'))
))
)
)
```

According to the error I am receiving, the (inputdata) variable cannot be transposed because it is not a matrix.  But it works just fine in the simulated tool.  Here is the server.R code for my real data set:

```
library(shiny)

ldamodel2 <- lda(predclass ~ Ageord2 + Hsehld_Incomeord6catchar2 + HlthStatusord2 + Hlth_Coverage_Typeord2 + WellnessEffort_HadVisitord2 + Genderord2 + Engagement_AlternativeMedord2 + Enguagement_RecievedERcareord2 + Engagement_TraveledIntlforCareord2, mixmodel, subset=ldamodel.traindata2)


pred_class <- function(ageord2, hsehld_incomeord6catchar2, hlthstatusord2, hlth_coverage_typeord2, wellnesseffort_hadvisitord2, genderord2, engagement_alternativemedord2, enguagement_recievedercareord2, engagement_traveledintlforcareord2){
inputdata <- c(ageord2, hsehld_incomeord6catchar2, hlthstatusord2, hlth_coverage_typeord2, wellnesseffort_hadvisitord2, genderord2, engagement_alternativemedord2, enguagement_recievedercareord2, engagement_traveledintlforcareord2)
pred_data <- as.data.frame(t(inputdata))
colnames(pred_data) <- c("Ageord2", "Hsehld_Incomeord6catchar2", "HlthStatusord2", "Hlth_Coverage_Typeord2", "WellnessEffort_HadVisitord2", "Genderord2", "Engagement_AlternativeMedord2", "Enguagement_RecievedERcareord2", "Engagement_TraveledIntlforCareord2")
ldamodel.predictions2 <- predict(ldamodel2, pred_data)
ldamodel.predictions2class <- ldamodel.predictions2$class
return(ldamodel.predictions2class)
}

shinyServer(
function(input, output) {
output$class <- renderText({pred_class(input$ageord2, input$hsehld_incomeord6catchar2, input$hlthstatusord2, input$hlth_coverage_typeord2, input$wellnesseffort_hadvisitord2, input$genderord2, input$engagement_alternativemedord2, input$enguagement_recievedercareord2, input$engagement_traveledintlforcareord2)
})

})
```

I realize that I cannot recreate the error, because the simulation works!  But if anyone has ever encountered this error before in this context, i am fairly new to r shiny and it would be a great help.  It may also be something incredibly stupid in the code i cannot see, from starring at it too long.  Even guesses from looking at the two would help.  Thanks!

Comment: How are you importing your 'real data'?  It may be automatically converted to another format on import.  Try importing your real data in an R session and compare to your simulated data.  You can check the structure of an object simply with `str`.

Comment: Both data sets are 'data.frame's.  One difference is that all of the simulated data are factors, while the 'real data' are factors and discrete numbers 1:5.  Should that matter for the transposition of the vector into columns at that stage in the function?  Also, testlca.predclass is an integer, while it seems to be a factor with the 'real data' set.  Thanks for the question @cdeterman !

Comment: Try running your app with it printing the class of `inputdata` right before the error happens (i.e. `print(class(inputedata))`).  The function doesn't think it is a matrix so you need to see what it is going in to the function that causes the error.

Comment: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5605
[1] "NULL"
Error in t.default(inputdata) : argument is not a matrix         This is the output i recieved upon entering print(class(inputdata))  it returned "NULL" for class.

Comment: It is printing NULL so somehow the data isn't being passed through.  As you say, it is difficult without reproducible data.  You will need to try and trace your data and see where it is getting lost.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman, I tried placing the `print(class(inputdata))`  in front of the working simulation to understand the difference and got the error:            `Error in class(inputdata) : argument "v4" is missing, with no default`                Does this mean that v4 is not making it through as well, or just that there is an error.    Also, I am not quite sure what you mean by "lost" data.  Does this mean that somewhere in the data cleaning process I may have classified or structured a dataset incorrectly, or that it is just not making it into the function for an ancillary reason?

Comment: You have created a function `class` that overwrites the base `class` function.  Change the name of your `class` function to something else and try again.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman, that worked for the simulated data.  The class was as expected:  `"character"`.  To insure that `inputdata` was being read as a character I emphasized this as:  `inputdata <- c('ageord2', 'hsehld_incomeord6catchar2', 'hlthstatusord2', ect ...')`  it worked, and and i placed `print(dim(pred_data))` after `pred_data <- as.data.frame(t(inputdata))`  and it transposed the vector into columns (making progress).  But now i receive:  `Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.pass, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor Ageord2 has new level ageord2`  ?

Comment: That error is now telling you that your new data has a new level that wasn't seen before.  You may need to manually adjust levels or split your data more evenly.